# How can I get current page name including $_GET variable in URL?

Tags: php, url, get

Let's say I have the page:

```
index.php?page=page-title-here
```

I want to get the current page name including the $_GET variable in the URL. 
I am currently using this:

```
basename(__FILE__)
```

It outputs "index.php", the actual file name. Any idea how to also include the $_GET variable so that it will output "index.php?page=page-title-here"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` gives you the file with GET parameters. Also includes folders in the url.

Edit: Use `$page = end(explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));` if you want to get rid of the folders from the url.

Comment: With only small fix. I had to use this instead
$explodeURL=explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$page_name_with_get_request = end($explodeURL);
Other way it would give me warning message: "Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference"

Answer (score 2):

You can do so using the `REQUEST_URI`:

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> **REQUEST_URI**: The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
$page = (__FILE__) . '?' . $_GET['page'];
```

Comment: It works after modification: $page_name_with_get_request = basename(______FILE______).'?page='.$_GET['page'];  but then I am fixed to "?page" and I have to use if statement for pages that will not have $_GET request in url.

Answer (score 0):

Try $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] (there are lots of interesting things in $_SERVER)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's issue, it is better to add context, or an explanation as to why this solves the OP's problem, so future visitors can learn from your post, and apply this knowledge to their own issues. High Quality Answers are much more likely to be upvoted, and contribute to the value and quality of SO as a platform. You can also add a link to documentation, if that helps.